# Boilerpipe - How do I output JSON?

Tags: java, json, boilerpipe

I am using [boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) and it seems great, but I want to output JSON. I am using the Java version and testing in NetBeans as follows:

```
final URL url = new URL("http://mashable.com/2012/09/26/worlds-best-father-kickstarter-calendar");
System.out.println(ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(url));
```

Can anyone tell me how I go about this?

Comment: If my answer did help, be kind and mark it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Boilerpipe` does not come with a `JSON` serializer.

You can, however, do this (assuming you already extracted all data):

```
public String articleTextToJson(String article, String title, String sourceUrl) {
    if (null == article) {
        return "{ \"error\" : { " +
               "       \"message\" : \"Article did not extract\", " +
               "       \"code\" : 1 " +
               "    }, " +
               "  \"status\" : \"error\" " +
               "}";
    }
    return "{ \"response\" : { " +
           "       \"title\" : \"" + title + "\" " +
           "       \"content\" : \"" + article + "\", " +
           "       \"source\" : \"" + sourceUrl + "\" " +
           "    }, " +
           "  \"status\" : \"success\" " +
           "}"
}
```

The tricky part will be of course getting the title...

Or better yet use some `JSON` serializer like [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cheers, i'm passing the title as a parameter

Comment: Great... so did you use this suggested function?

Comment: No i have a made a servlet that does what i needed to do. It builds a json string using the extracted content and the title passed in as a parameter.